# error ngx toastr

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy teniendo un problema lo instale hace unos días, y me salta este error al parecer le faltan suficientes argumentos para funcionar, decidí no volverme loca, y di de baja en los componentes que estaba usando e intentar versiones mas simples.

¿Hay alguna forma de realizar un clean seguro???

Ahora estoy tratando de conectar mi front con firebase y cuando le doy a **`ng build`** salta este error, y no quiero continuar hasta no tener claro este problema!!

Disculpen si es una pregunta muy básica, es la primera vez que lo uso, no me había saltado ningún error hasta este momento.

[image: lo use para logear]

**Edicion:** muestro uno de mis compontes y su ts con el que uso de toastr:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-floating float-end" 
               type="button" *ngIf="isAdmin" 
routerLink="/newhistorial">agregahistorial</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let Historial of historial">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <h1> Experiencia</h1>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <p>{{Historial.empresa}}</p>
            </li> 
            <li> <h3>{{Historial.periodo}} - </h3>
            </li> 
            <h4>{{Historial.puesto}} - </h4>
            <h4> {{Historial.actividades}} </h4> 
        </ul>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-floating float-end"  *ngIf="isAdmin 
==true"routerLink="/edithistorial/{{Historial.id}}">edit
            </button>
        </div>
        <div >
            <button class="btn btn-floating float-end"  *ngIf="isAdmin 
                   == true" (click)="delete(Historial.id)">delete </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El ts, sin el uso de ngx toastr es como lo edite ayer:

```
export class HistorialComponent implements OnInit {
  historial: Historial[]=[];
  isLogged = environment.isLogged;
  public historials:Historial;
  form: FormGroup;
  roles:string[];
  isAdmin=false;

  constructor(private historiales:HistorialService,
                             private tokenService:TokenService) { 
    this.form= new FormGroup({
      imagen: new FormControl(['', [Validators.required, 
                     Validators.minLength(1)]]),
      empresa: new FormControl([ '', [Validators.required, 
                      Validators.minLength(2)]]),
      puesto:  new FormControl(['', [Validators.required, 
                      Validators.minLength(2)]]),
      periodo:  new FormControl(['', [Validators.required, 
                      Validators.minLength(2)]]),
      actividades:  new FormControl(['', [Validators.required, 
                          Validators.minLength(2)]]),
    } )
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cargarExperiencia();
    this.roles = this.tokenService.getAuthorities();
    this.roles.forEach(rol => {
      if (rol === 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
        this.isAdmin = true;
      }
    });
  }

  cargarExperiencia(): void {
    this.historiales.lista().subscribe(
      data =>  { this.historial = data; },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      } 
    );
  }

  delete(id?: number){
    if(id != undefined){
      this.historiales.delete(id).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.cargarExperiencia();
        }, err => {
          alert("No se pudo borrar la experiencia");
        }
      )
    }
  }

  private mostrarExperiencia(){
    this.historiales.lista().subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        this.historial = data;
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    )}
  }
```

Acá esta con el uso de toastr, espero sea mas claro.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-historial',
  templateUrl: './historial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./historial.component.css']
})
export class HistorialComponent implements OnInit {
  historial: Historial[]=[];
  isLogged = environment.isLogged;
  public historials:Historial;
  form: FormGroup;
  roles:string[];
  isAdmin=false;

  constructor( private historiales: HistorialService,
                     private tokenService:TokenService,
                     private toastr: ToastrService) { 
    this.form= new FormGroup({
      imagen: new FormControl(['', [Validators.required, 
                         Validators.minLength(1)]]),
      empresa: new FormControl([ '', [Validators.required, 
                  Validators.minLength(2)]]),
      puesto:  new FormControl(['', [Validators.required, 
                  Validators.minLength(2)]]),
      periodo:  new FormControl(['', [Validators.required, 
                     Validators.minLength(2)]]),
      actividades:  new FormControl(['', [Validators.required, 
                     Validators.minLength(2)]]),
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cargarExperiencia();

    this.roles = this.tokenService.getAuthorities();
    this.roles.forEach(rol => {
      if (rol === 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
        this.isAdmin = true;
      }
    });
  }

  cargarExperiencia(): void {
    this.historiales.lista().subscribe(
      data => { this.historial = data; },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  delete(id?: number){
    if(id != undefined){
      this.historiales.delete(id).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.toastr.success('Producto Eliminado', 'OK', {
            timeOut: 3000, positionClass: 'toast-top-center'
          });
          this.cargarExperiencia();
        }, err => {
          this.toastr.error(err.error.mensaje, 'Fail', {
          timeOut: 3000, positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
        });
        // alert("No se pudo borrar la experiencia");
      }
    )}
  }

  private mostrarExperiencia(){
    this.historiales.lista().subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        this.historial = data;
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
```

Perdón que de tantas vueltas es la primera vez que uso esta herramienta, espero tenga solución!!!!

Comment: se que no es la mejor publicacion pero solo recibo (- )pero ningun comentario acerca de que debo corregir!! alguien podria decirme a que se refiere con esos arumentos que faltan ?? gracias

Comment: Saludos @carolina, como bien dices extrañamente nadie te explicó el por qué de tus negativos, según veo lo que sucede es que debes agregar toda la información necesaria, por ejemplo dices: "*estoy tratando de conectar mi front con firebase y cuando le doy a ng build salta este error*" muchas veces se puede identificar el error solo con verlo pero en otras necesitas agregar el código que estas utilizando para que un usuario de la comunidad pueda replicar el error y segundo siempre agrega el código y el error en formato de texto y no así como captura, las capturas solo cuando las necesites. ;)

Comment: hola Israel-ICM gracias por el comentario,mira en mi componentes,lo estaba usando en delete,cuando empezaron a saltar los errores los elimine por competo,pero sigue marcando el mismo error
  delete(id?: number){ if(id != undefined){
      this.historiales.delete(id).subscribe(
        data =>{
          this.toastr.success('experiencia Eliminado', 'OK',{
          timeOut: 3000, positionClass: 'toast-top-center' });
          this.cargarExperiencia();
        }, err =>{
        this.toastr.error(err.error.mensaje, 'Fail', {
        timeOut: 3000, positionClass: 'toast-top-center', });

Comment: voy a tratar de subir nuevamente la pregunta con todos los datos, para ver la correcion, en realidad me serviria saber si ahora que no uso esta extension puedo borrarla para evitar estos rojos al cargar, estuve buscando el codigo de uninstall completo y seguro pero no lo encuentro, no se si sera por que no se puede o porque no he podido dar con el enlace o ayuda  con esto

Comment: Recuerda que siempre puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/586462/edit) la pregunta que tienes actualmente.